# Noobie issue. PHP else if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I'm hitting my head to a  wall... This is a fraction of my code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT vote,id FROM votes WHERE post_id = ? AND user_id = ? "); 
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $post_id, $user_id);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($result, $vote_id);
$stmt->fetch();
$num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();

if ($num_rows>=1)
{

if ($result!==$vote)   
{        
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE votes SET vote = ? WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $vote, $vote_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}

else if ($result==$vote) 
{
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE votes SET vote = 0 WHERE id=?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $vote_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}    
}
```

No errors are shown, the script works just fine until it reaches ELSE IF part. It doesn't update although $vote value is the same as in a database.

Comment: you don't need an `else **if**` just an `else`, its either going to be match or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!==` is a [strict comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and this statement is saying that `$result` must not be **identical** (in type as well as value) to `$vote`. You don't need to be that specific for this.

```
if ($result!==$vote)
```

What you should be doing is this:

```
if ($result != $vote) // only one equal sign, not two
{
   ...
} else { // they are equal implicitly, no need to redefine the ==
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 can only assume `$vote` is an integer whilst any result from `bind_result` / `fetch` will be a string

Comment: @Phil, yeah $vote is either 1 or -1... So the reason of this issue is different data types? And how should I make them both int?

Comment: @SauliusSlavinskas Just use `!=` instead, it automatically converts variable types and compares them.

Comment: @scrowler God bless ya! Just tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SauliusSlavinskas For completeness, you can also cast `$result` to an integer via `(int) $result`

Comment: @Phil yeah that sounds reasonable.